# google map marker info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i am using gmap api v 3
after i open info window using marker.there is small close button 
appearing on right top of the info window.
how can i do away with that close button and rather have my own button.

here is code tha that i have for opening infor window.

```
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { content: "",
      size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
  });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an infoBox details [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/docs/reference.html)

hope this helps...

Comment: where can i find infobox.js that is required?

Comment: i am not sure you need it, but if you do it is usually added by appending the url with the library name.